# arguments.shift() is not a function, Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot for someone and there is this command that I get stuck on, the `giverole` one. Particularly, the `arguments.shift` part of it.

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}giverole`)) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
      message.channel.send("Vous n'avez pas la permission d'utiliser cette commande.")
      return;
    }
    const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!targetUser) {
      message.reply('Please specify someone to give a role to.')
      return
    }

    arguments.shift()

    const roleName = arguments.join(' ')
    const { guild } = message

    const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
      return role.name === roleName
    })
    if (!role) {
      message.reply(`There is no role with the name "${roleName}"`)
      return
    }

    const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUser.id)
    member.roles.add(role)

    message.reply(`that user now has the "${roleName}" role`)
  }
}
```

And I receive this error:

```
TypeError: arguments.shift is not a function
```

The error may be that arguments isn't passed anywhere, yet I don't know where to place it.

Comment: Yes, sorry for not doing so before hand, but I was out of town and didn't have acces to internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've never defined `arguments` (which wouldn't be a wise choice for a variable name anyway, as there is an [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) in normal functions).

Instead of getting custom arguments from the message and searching the role by its name, you could mention the role(s) and get them by using `message.mentions.roles`. This way you don't have to chop and clean up the `message.content` either.

```js
client.on('message', async (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}giverole`)) {
    if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
      return message.channel.send(
        "Vous n'avez pas la permission d'utiliser cette commande.",
      );
    }

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();
    const member = message.guild.member(user);
    const role = message.mentions.roles.first();

    if (!member) {
      return message.reply('Please mention someone to give a role to.');
    }

    if (!role) {
      return message.reply(`Please mention a role to add to ${member}.`);
    }

    try {
      await member.roles.add(role);
      message.reply(`${member} now has the "${role}" role`);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      message.reply(`Role "${role}" is not added to ${member}.\n_${error}_`);
    }
  }
});
```

[image]

PS: Make sure to drag your bot's role above all other roles in your server settings and give it the `Manage Roles` permission to avoid `DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `arguments` like this:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
  let arguments = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
  // Rest of your code
})
```

Comment: It technically works, but it does not separate all of it, I only want :
```
role
```
But I get:
```
@someone role
```
https://imgur.com/a/EFJvAT5

Comment: Well you access different parts by indexing right? Like arguments[0] etc.